# python2 interpreter in Docker does not support remote project creation with PyCharm

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, remote-access

I am using PyCharm 2017.1.1 on Windows 10 Pro with Docker for Windows.
The Python2 (Anaconda2) interpreter in docker works well.
However, it does not support project creation. How can I solve this problem?

[image: The interpreter does not support remote project creation]

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue - but the problem is not Windows, as this error still occurs when trying to create a docker interpreter without Docker-Compose

I have found that you  can get around the error by creating a project using the File>open menu and selecting a folder, then retrospectively assigning the docker interpreter to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-docker-compose.html):

> **Limitation**
>
> As of this writing, Docker Compose integration in PyCharm is not supported on Windows.